# Extract only values from a dicts inside a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How to extract every value from each dictionary nested within a list?
Currently I'm stuck with a list comprehension that accepts one key.

```
d = [e["key1"] for e in list]
```

Sample

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value4', 'key4': 'value4'}]
```

Need to get

```
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

Comment: `[x for d in list_of_dicts for x in d.values()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all and @kaya3!

```
[x for d in list_of_dicts for x in d.values()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> vals = []
>>> for d in d_list:
    vals += list(d.values())
        
>>> vals
['value1', 'value2', 'value4', 'value4']
```

Answer (score 1):

via itertools chain -

```
l  = [{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value4', 'key4': 'value4'}]

from itertools import chain
result = list(chain(*(item.values() for item in l)))
```

Via list comprehension -

```
result = [val for i in l for val in i.values()]
```